# D3.js bar chart issue with updating the data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a dataset of students details and their grades in math.
I'm trying to create a bar chart where the x axis represent the grade (can be between 0 and 20) and the y axis represent the number of student that have this grade.
I want to show the data by the selected school.
When the chart is set for the GP school the graph looks okay:

[image]

But when I update the data to the second school ("MS") the graph looks like that :

[image]

Link to the dataset I'm using :
https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/student-alcohol-consumption?select=student-mat.csv

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: tahoma;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .x.axis path {
        display: none;
        }
        .bar { fill: steelblue; }
        .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 28px;
        pointer-events: none;
        font-weight : bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Add 2 buttons -->
    <button onclick="update('GP')">Grades by GP school</button>
    <button onclick="update('MS')">Grades by MS school</button>

    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
 

<script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    // Initialize the X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ 0, width ])
      .padding(0.2);
    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    
    // Initialize the Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([ height, 0]);
    var yAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "myYaxis")
    
      var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
    // A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
    function update(selectedVar) {
        var arr = [];
      // Parse the Data
      d3.csv("student-mat.csv", function(data) {
        //data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.school == selectedVar })
        data = data.filter(function(row) {
            return row['school'] == selectedVar;
        })
        data.map(function(d){
            arr.push(+d.G3);
        });
        console.log(arr);
        var counts = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var num = arr[i];
            counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
        }
       var test = [];
       for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(counts)) {
             test.push({name:key,score:value});
        }
       console.log(test);
       
       // X axis
        x.domain(test.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
        xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x))

        // Add Y axis
        y.domain([0, d3.max(test, function(d) { return d.score}) ]);
        yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        // variable u: map data to existing bars
        var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(test)

        // update bars
        u
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .merge(u)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.score); })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.score); })
            .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
    })

    }

    // Initialize plot
    update('GP')

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the MS school graph to look exactly like the GP school graph?

Comment: Can you `console.log(text)` before `var u = svg.selectAll("rect").data(test)` ? What do you see?

Comment: I printed my data array (test) and it prints the right numbers.

Comment: Is it just numbers or objects? Can you post a sample of the data from console?